# How to use top level collections in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to use `Top Level Collections` concept described in [this](http://ndpsoftware.com/HibernateMappingCheatSheet.html) post :

Here is some part of that post :

> Top-level Collections
>
> A top-level collection is a collection defined outside of the scope of
>   an individual class and available for use in all classes in the
>   mapping files. Scenario
>
> We have one class, Foo, and a collection of Strings (e.g. people's
>   names) which we wish to make available to other classes without
>   constantly declaring set definitions inside each one.

```
Set Foo.getNames() // of String instances
```

---

```
<set role="names" table="names">
    <key column="id" type="string">
        <generator class="uuid.hex"/>
    </key>
    <element column="name" type="string"/>
</set>
<class name="Foo" table="foo"> 
    ... 
    <collection name="names" column="name_id" role="names"/> 
</class>
```

> Note that a top-level collection needs its own key generator, and that
>   this cannot be of the assigned type since it is never exposed to a
>   calling application.
>
> Again, Person does not represents a class. It is simply a collection
>   of second-rank persistent objects - in this case Strings. Note also
>   that Names simply has id not foo_id. This is to allow it to be used by
>   a variety of classes. Also, because we cannot use Person's id as a
>   foo_id, we have added a person_id FK to Foo. Bidirectionality
>
> There's no bidirectional relationship available here as there is only
>   one class involved.

When I tried to use `<set>` element in mapping above the `<class>` element, I started getting errors. I think hibernate is not able to identify `<set>` outside `<class>` element.

Anyone knows how to use `Top Level Collections`?

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

That cheat sheet is a very old one, based on information on a website that no longer exists.

I found a discussion from 2002 where Gavin King discusses to no longer support it in hibernate 2: http://www.mail-archive.com/hibernate-devel@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01188.html

In the hibernate-mapping-1.1.dtd, (available from http://www.jboss.org/dtd/hibernate/) the top elements were:

```
<!ELEMENT hibernate-mapping ( 
    (map|set|list|bag|array|primitive-array)*, 
    class*,
    query*
)>
```

In hibernate-mapping-2.0.dtd, it is:

```
<!ELEMENT hibernate-mapping (
    meta*,
    import*, 
    (class|subclass|joined-subclass)*, 
    query*, 
    sql-query*
)>
```

In hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd:

```
<!ELEMENT hibernate-mapping (
    meta*,
    identifier-generator*,
    typedef*,
    filter-def*,
    import*,
    (class|subclass|joined-subclass|union-subclass)*,
    resultset*,
    (query|sql-query)*,
    filter-def*,
    fetch-profile*,
    database-object*
)>
```

Top level collections in hibernate have been burried long ago.

Comment: If I want to implement similar functionality in hibernate 3 version then how can I do that?